# How do I configure WebSphere MQ distribution lists on the server side?

Tags: queue, messaging, ibm-mq

Does anybody have experience with configuring distribution lists (sending a message to one queue, and having that message be forwarded to several other queues) for Websphere MQ v7? I want to configure it on my queue manager, rather than the client having to know all the queues to send the messages to. Also, I would prefer not to use a topic, because I want to be able to manage each queue separately. Is there some configuration file, or some way to use WebSphere MQ Explorer to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A program that uses a distribution list doesn't have to "know" the queues it sends to in the sense of hard-coding the names.  But it *does* have to supply the list of queue names.  Typically you can place these into a namelist and have the sending program retrieve them there.  When the program calls `PUT` it must also be prepared to parse a structure of return codes rather than a single MQRC.

However, you really should reconsider using a topic.  You can create administrative subscriptions for each destination queue.  This allows you to send the publications to any local or remote queue that you like.  It also have the advantage of being able to add or delete destinations without having to restart - or worse, recompile - the sending application.

You can use WMQ Explorer either to manage a namelist or to manage the topic and administrative subscriptions.  The topic/subscriptions method is the only way to do this purely through configuration.  To use distribution lists requires a program specifically designed for the purpose.